# How to access functional component inside a function from an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

```js
export default function HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState({});


   const handleComplete = () => {
     const newCompleted = completed;
     newCompleted[activeStep] = true;
     setCompleted(newCompleted);
     handleNext();
  };
```

```js
<button
  className="footerSaveButton"
  disabled={
    selectedCoach || selectedValue || selectedCustomer
      ? disabled
      : !disabled
  }
  onClick={routeChange}

  // onClick= {() => {routeChange();handleComplete();}}
     
>
  Save and Continue
</button>
```

There is a const type functional component inside an export default function. I want to access that functional component on my button click that is also inside a function from an external JS file.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: yes sure but this site is not allowing me to post screenshot.can u help me on that?

Comment: It would be much more convenient for us if you give us the code as text, not an image.

Comment: <button
            className="footerSaveButton"
            disabled={
              selectedCoach || selectedValue || selectedCustomer
                ? disabled
                : !disabled
            }
            onClick={routeChange}
 
            // onClick= {() => {routeChange();handleComplete();}}
 
          >
            Save and Continue
          </button>

Comment: export default function HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState({});

  
   const handleComplete = () => {
    const newCompleted = completed;
    newCompleted[activeStep] = true;
    setCompleted(newCompleted);
    handleNext();
  };

Comment: Please edit the code into your question. That way it can be formatted all nicely. Comments don't have that ability.

Comment: i want to fire the 'handlecomplete' functional component on the 'save and continue' button click.

Comment: added..plz help..

Comment: 'handle complete' and the 'save and continue' are not in same JS file.

Comment: r u able to see my code?as m new in stackoverflow.

Comment: You have to pass the `handleComplete` function as a prop from `HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper` component to the component rendering the `<button />`.

Comment: As m new in react Can U plz give d exact code?

Comment: I’ve edited your question to use code blocks instead of stack snippets — please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.